# Xamarin form: Native control onDraw never get called

Tags: android, xamarin, custom-controls, ondraw, renderer

I have xamarin form which building a native control. I have extended the ViewRenderer and the touch event in the native control can detect the mouse event. On the other hand, I override the onDraw but it was never get called, even I called invalidate and setWillNotDraw to false.

```
public class CanvasViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CanvasView, ImageView> 
{
    private ImageView _ImageView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CanvasView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            _ImageView = new ImageView(Context);
            page = new Page();
            var directory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            var imagePath = directory + "/A.png";
            _ImageView.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + imagePath));
            _ImageView.SetWillNotDraw(false);
            SetNativeControl(_ImageView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        { 
            Control.Touch -= CanvasTouchEvent;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)   
        { 
            Control.Touch += CanvasTouchEvent;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        var strokes = page.GetStrokes();

        if (strokes != null && strokes.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < strokes.Count(); i++)
            {
                var stroke = strokes.ElementAt(i);

                if (stroke.GetPointerId() != -1)
                { 
                    if (stroke.GetPath() != null)
                        canvas.DrawPath(stroke.GetPath(), new Paint());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```